# require() on gzip'd file returning wrong-MIME-type error

Tags: javascript, requirejs, compression, gzip, mime-types

Here are my require calls:

```
    require( ['config'], function( config ) {
        require( ['main'] );
    });
```

They are pathed to a CDN (AWS S3 + CloudFront) that has gzipped config.js and main.js.

Pertinent parts of my Headers:

Browser:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
```

File:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/x-gzip
```

In Safari this works fine.  In Chrome and Firefox I get this error:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   application/x-gzip: "http://sample.com/config.js".

And it never decompresses.
I've tried setting scriptType='application/x-gzip' within the require config but that just freezes things.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did also try the files outside of require in just plain old <script> tags and they still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple, doh!

On the server side, I had the `content-type` set to `application/x-gzip`.  This is actually misleading because that is describing the content BEFORE the compression (and thus, AFTER the decompression, as well).  The `content-encoding` is the one that specifies the actual compression step.

To fix, I simply set the `content-type` on the gzip'd file on the server side to the appropriate type of the original file: `text/javascript` or `text/css`, etc.